# MySQL self-join with order by optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-order-by, self-join

I have such a query:

```
SELECT va.value, vc.value
FROM votingapi_cache va
LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache vc ON vc.content_id = va.content_id
WHERE va.content_type = 'node' AND va.value_type = 'percent' AND va.tag = 'vote' AND va.function = 'average' AND vc.content_type = 'node' AND vc.tag = 'vote' AND vc.function = 'count'
ORDER BY va.value DESC, vc.value DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

EXPLAIN tells me that this query uses temporary and filesort. It runs nearly 10s on table with 500k rows. How it can be optimized?

Schema:

[image]

Indexes:

[image]

After suggestions given by [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892994/706261), no performance improvements, EXPLAIN:

[image]

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I'm going to assume there is a good reason why average and count aren't computed by aggregate functions.

Comment: It's actually a Drupal's votingapi module table (there is another table votingapi_vote which contains all votes - aroud 18 million rows), which contains already agregated and cached results.

Comment: Please add the execution plan. Also the output from `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` for these two tables would be useful. You could also start by removing content_type from each of the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to break the join into two queries ...

First, build an index on column `function, value`,

Your first query should be getting the best average,
because this is the first sorting value,
such as :

```
SELECT average.value, average.content_id
FROM votingapi_cache average
WHERE average.function = 'average' /* plus other filter *
ORDER BY average.value DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Then, loop thru the 30 rows to get the content_id,
and your second second query is to get the 30 rows of count for each content_id,
that's mean :

```
select count.value, count.content_id
FROM votingapi_cache `count`
WHERE `count`.function = 'count'
and content_id in(...30 content_id);
```

loop thru the 2nd results and combine with the first result to get best 10 average + count desc

this can avoid massive join

Comment: It will indeed avoid the join, but beware that 30 is a sort of 'adjust to a value sufficiently above 10 until it works for your dataset' limit. If set too low, it may not give the same result as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ajreal's answer, you could do it like -

```
SELECT averages.value, counts.value
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM votingapi_cache
    WHERE function = 'average'
    AND content_type = 'node'
    AND tag = 'vote'
    AND value_type = 'percent'
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 0, 30
) AS averages
LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache counts
    ON averages.content_id = counts.content_id
    AND averages.content_type = counts.content_type
    AND averages.value_type = counts.value_type
    AND averages.tag = counts.tag
WHERE counts.function = 'count'
ORDER BY averages.value DESC, counts.value DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```